# Enumerating Games

Tags: enumerate

I would like to enumerate these three games. Could someone please help me with that? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage=false]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{sgame, tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\hspace{2cm}
\item \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $1, -1$ & $-1, 1$  \\
     Tails  &  $-1, 1$ & $1, -1$\\
\end{game}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\hspace{2cm}
\item \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $2, 2$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 1$\\
\end{game}
\end{table}

\vspace{-2.7cm}
\begin{table}[h!]
\hspace{9.5cm}
\item \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $3, 1$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 3$\\
\end{game}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For one, don't put a floating `table` inside of an `enumerate` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

Changes: don't use `table` or `center` inside an `enumerate`; end your `enumerate`.  I added a leading `\hfil` to push the games rightward, though that may not be what you want.

If you wanted the `enumerate` labels more toward the horizontal center, you could consider setting the `enumerate` inside a narrower `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage=false]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{sgame, tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\hfil \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $1, -1$ & $-1, 1$  \\
     Tails  &  $-1, 1$ & $1, -1$\\
\end{game}

\item\hfil \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $2, 2$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 1$\\
\end{game}

\item\hfil \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $3, 1$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 3$\\
\end{game}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, if you wanted it in a floating `table`, then remove the `enumerate` and add manual labels:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage=false]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{sgame, tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My game tables}
\centering
1) \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $1, -1$ & $-1, 1$  \\
     Tails  &  $-1, 1$ & $1, -1$\\
\end{game}\bigskip

2) \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $2, 2$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 1$\\
\end{game}\bigskip

3) \begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  Heads      &  Tails     \\
     Heads  &  $3, 1$ & $0, 0$  \\
     Tails  &  $0, 0$ & $1, 3$\\
\end{game}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough space, I need the third to be placed next to the other two games. I thought I could add 1. or i. just before the game. But it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: @Eduard I do not understand your comment.  Perhaps you are saying you could remove them from the `enumerate` and manually label them?  Yes you could.

Comment: @Eduard Please the my answer edit, in which I provide an additional alternative.

Comment: Thanks, the additional alternative was very helpful.